# How do I get Visual Studio to do vbscript syntax highlighting for .asp files?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, syntax-highlighting

asp files are highlighted as html in Visual Studio 2008 unless I put language=vbscript in all my <% > code blocks. lame! when I go to tools -> options -> text editor -> file extention I don't get vbscript or vb as an option, only c#, c++, html, etc

Comment: Do you have SP1 installed? Seems they fixed it: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=292379

Comment: yeah, I have SP1 and the Visual Basic choice for editor is still missing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

turns out VB wasn't installed :P

1. make sure it is
2. in VS, go to tools -> options -> text editor -> file extension
3. add asp as the extension and pick Visual Basic as the editor

Comment: I have VB installed but it is not showing as an option in 'tools -> options -> text editor -> file extension'. I can create VB projects and all works fine...its just not showing up in the "Editor" drop-down list. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. I managed to adjust the VBScript text Editor colors in interim by going to

```
TOOLS -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts & Colors
```

**Show Settings For:** Text Editor

**Display Items:** scroll down to VBScript and ***adjust the colors*** for each item.

It's not perfect but at least it is not B&W anymore.

Answer (score -2):

Go to IE ,Tools-->Inter net Options-->Advanced--> Browsing --> Uncheck Disable Script Debugging(IE)--->Hit Apply Button

Then got to your VS

Tools --> Options --> Text Editor --> File Extensions --> On the Right Pane,Type your File Extension which you want to Debug(Ex: vb (or) js) in Extensions Box, Choose Editor "Script Editor" -->Hit Add Button --> Check "Map Extension Files to" ---> Select "Microsoft Visual C#" -->Enter "OK" Button Now you run the application and debug the script.

Comment: He was not talking about debugging.